# What is the best way to change a set during iterations?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdset

Given `std::set` , what is the best way to change the set during time-iteration?
For example:

```
std::set<T> s;  // T is a some type (it's not important for the question).
// insertions to s
for (std::set<T>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++) {
        T saveIt(*it);
        s.erase(*it);
        s.insert( saveIt + saveIt );  // operator+ that defined at `T`
}
```

According to what that I  read in some sources, it's bad way because that: the removing from the set may change the structure of the set.

So what is the better (/best) way to do it?

Comment: You have to use the resulting iterator from your function to update `it` correctly.(but you risk to iterate on the new item too)

Comment: What's the point of doing this in-place to begin with?

Comment: @Jarod42 Now it's ok according to what you say? (I edited the question)

Comment: Is space a constraint? This is a bad idea like you mention, a new `set` would be an easy solution.

Comment: Well std::set works by keeping all the items in order according to the object's < operator. If you remove and add a new item, the set order will be different...

Comment: @RvdK And hence I asked this qeustion, how can I do it in despite to this fact?

Comment: Well easiest to create a new std::set, and store the new T object in it.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ok , you right, so can you explain how to do it? (I understand what you mean, but don't understand how to do it. But, I do'nt think that it's going to solve the problem - like that explaing in the comment of "Rvdk".

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Ok , like that I writed in my question, after that I writed this code, I already understood that it's "it's bad way" (like that I mentioned in my question) , and hence, I am looking for a better way to do it. (I mentioned the example only for explain what I mean while I say "to change a set during iterations" - this is the first way that I thought for how to do it)

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: That depends how `operator <` and `operator +` are implemented. (with something like `std::set<int, std::greater<>>`, it would be ok).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a copy std:set

```
std::set<T> s;
std::set<T> modified_s;
for (std::set<T>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++) {
    modified_s.insert(*it+ *it);
}
s = std::move(modified_s);
```

Edit:
Added `std::move` as improvement from @Jodocus

Comment: `s = std::move(modified_s);` would be closer to the original's intent  instead of `clear`.

Answer (score 7):

Your loop may result in almost endless loop because you keep adding larger elements at the back of your set. Until `T + T` overflows.

Correct way is to create a new set:

```
std::set<T> s; 
std::set<T> s2; 
for(auto const& elem : s)
    s2.insert(elem + elem);
s.swap(s2);
```

With `boost::range` it is a one-liner:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
// ...
std::set<int> s;
s = boost::copy_range<std::set<int>>(s | boost::adaptors::transformed([](int x) { return x + x; }));
```

Comment: Since C++11, `s = std::move(s2);` is enough ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 It is longer, is it better though?

Comment: Intention is clearer, (swap is a valid implementation of move assignment BTW). moment of destruction of original data might also differ (extended to `s2` lifetime with the `swap`).